# Difference between && and where condition in entity framework query

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, if-statement

### Difference between and condition and two where condition in entity framework query

**Code 1**

I have using two where condition in my query

```
 dbContext.Projects.Where(p=>p.ProjectId!=ProjectId).Where(p=>p.Name==Name)
 .SingleOrDefault();
```

---

**code 2**

I have using && condition without using two where condition

```
  dbContext.Projects.Where(p=>p.ProjectId!=ProjectId &&  
  p.Name==Name).SingleOrDefault();
```

---

- What is the difference between **code1** and **code2**????

> The both queries are return same value. but i don't know the differences. Please explain to me, which one is better. and why?

Comment: well they wouldnt be the same if your users projectid was equal to the projectid you are checking against

Comment: @pala_ , how? can you explain little more? i don't understand

Comment: take a look at the generated sql statement and you will know - i assume they will be identical, so no difference.

Comment: nevermind - i misread it completely

Comment: You want to know the difference in this example or you question is about pros and cos for using two `where` instead of `&&`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you open your query in `LinqPad` you will see that both queries

```
dbContext.Projects.Where(p=>p.ProjectId!=ProjectId).Where(p=>p.Name==Name)

dbContext.Projects.Where(p=>p.ProjectId!=ProjectId && p.Name==Name);
```

will result both in

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...]
WHERE p.ProjectId <> someId AND p.Name = 'something'
```

There is no difference neither in performance nor in SQL query structure.

Comment: beat me to it, I was just typing.. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation

> Return value:
>
> An IEnumerable that contains elements from the input sequence that
>   satisfy the condition.

So the second `where` will only be applied to the records surviging the first `where` - which is identical to the && expression you built in code 2.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Both queries are same. But `Query 2` will give you better performance, as `&&` will help you in [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). In the first query, first `where` will yield the result and that will be given to 2nd `where` clause and then it will evaluate result based on the input. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: theoretically yes, but I would take a look at the generated sql - note that it is linq to sql (dbContext). linq does some pretty amazing optimizations...

Comment: Yes, it does optimize queries. But it will still go with preference order, isn't it? (not sure, in this scenario) To addon, in general boolean calculations are faster than linq, right? :)

Comment: sure, but I assume it will combine in SELECT *  WHERE ... AND .... for both codes. for linq to sql, the second where will not be executed on the result set, but integrated into the first - I assume, but have not tried ;-)