# Difference between Linq Where( ConditionA && ConditionB ) vs Where(ConditionA).Where(ConditionB))

Tags: c#, linq

What is the difference between `Where( ConditionA && ConditionB )` vs `Where(ConditionA).Where(ConditionB))`

When is one preferred over the other?

Edit 1 : I have an already enumerated IEnumerable , would it be different if it was not enumerated?

Edit 2: This is not about performance as the set being filtered is already small, wondering just about order of execution. The filter was already applied in web service call.

Comment: The 2nd will filter on the 1st condition and *then* on the 2nd condition. The 1st will filter on both conditions at the same time.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070011/difference-between-and-where-condition-in-entity-framework-query

Comment: @Dennis_E : What about the first one? What if I changed it to `Where( ConditionB && ConditionA )` then would both be the same?

Comment: @Dennis_E That's not necessary true. Depends on what the source is (and what query provider it's using). Query provider is allowed to merge them if it thinks it will be more performant. Also, Linq to Objects will basically merge second one into the first one too. See http://marcinjuraszek.com/2013/08/did-you-know-about-that-linq-feature.html

Comment: @MD.NazmulKibria : That is about EF, would it be the same for LINQ?

Comment: I suppose. At least the 1st one "looks" better.

Comment: LINQ to what? LINQ to SQL, LINQ to XML, LINQ to Objects, LINQ to Entities?

Comment: The answer is that it depends on what you're querying.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek : Linq to Objects, I assumed LINQ stands for LINQ to object, other wise would have mentioned the LINQ to X.

Comment: LINQ is just the query language. EF is the ORM that executes that query. If you want to check for differences, you can log and check the generated SQL statements *and* their execution plans. Queries that look different can result in the same execution plan

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : Already enumerated to IEnumerable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Just LINQ to objects, already have an enumerated of IEnumerable<WhatEver>

Comment: @Arjang then you have a bug. By enumerating to IEnumerable you loaded *everything* in memory. The two statements aren't that different by this point, except that the double `Where` results in two function calls on the same record, nothing more. The cost of loading everything in memory though is about 1M times worse

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : It was already filtered from service, this is the minimum set I get, This is not about performance as the result set is small, just about order of execution

Comment: @Arjang then it's a matter of convenience. Multiple `Where` statements can be added dynamically. A single `Where (.. && ..)` can't. If you want to use dynamic filters, multiple `Where` statements are acceptable. It doesn't justify generating the entire Expression in code, if that's what you're asking