# Entity Framework: Any benefit of writing aggregated queries vs spiting into several statements?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

Recently I have been dealing with some rather large queries with Entity Framework due to numerous joined tables. Basically I have now changed by wring style from:

```
dbContext.ModelX.Where(t=>
  t.prop1 == propCheck1 && 
  t.prop2 == propCheck2 && 
  t.prop3.prop31 == propCheck31)
```

Into:

```
dbContext.ModelX.
  .Where(t=> prop1 == propCheck1)
  .Where(t=> prop2 == propCheck2)
  .Where(t=> prop3.prop31 == propCheck31)
```

This is much more readable and easy to refactor for me, but I'm wondering:

- Are there any performance issues?
- Is my code following best practices?

Comment: when you looked at the generated SQL, what differences did you see?

Comment: You could use SQL Profiler, capture both statements then run execution plans, you can also see this in debug mode in VS,  see where the differences are.  I am pretty sure the first query would be quicker than the second query, but I could be wrong.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070011/difference-between-and-where-condition-in-entity-framework-query